# HIbernate StaleObject exception continuously on a thread

Tags: hibernate, hibernateexception

In one of our production environments we get hibernatestaleobject exception on a thread continuously after it appears first. This continues till we restart the server.

Environment: oracle 10g, WAS 6.1, Hibernate 2.1

Stack trace is below.

We are unable to simulate this in any other environment.

```
net.sf.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) for com.cmp1.project1.hibernate.gen.Prjexe instance with identifier: 37120123
at net.sf.hibernate.persister.AbstractEntityPersister.check(AbstractEntityPersister.java:506)
at net.sf.hibernate.persister.EntityPersister.update(EntityPersister.java:687)
at net.sf.hibernate.persister.EntityPersister.update(EntityPersister.java:642)
at net.sf.hibernate.impl.ScheduledUpdate.execute(ScheduledUpdate.java:52)
at net.sf.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.executeAll(SessionImpl.java:2418)
at net.sf.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.execute(SessionImpl.java:2372)
at net.sf.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:2240)
at com.cmp1.project1.hibernate.client.HibernateClient.update(HibernateClient.java:214)
at com.cmp1.project1.hibernate.client.HibernateClient.update(HibernateClient.java:165)
at com.cmp1.project1.util.project1Utils.persist(project1Utils.java:3018)
at com.cmp1.project1.util.project1Utils.update(project1Utils.java:1166)
at com.cmp1.project1.service.allocation.AllocationImpl.insert(AllocationImpl.java:917)
at com.cmp1.project1.service.allocation.AllocationImpl.create(AllocationImpl.java:239)
at com.cmp1.project1.ejb.allocation.AllocationBean.create(AllocationBean.java:91)
at com.cmp1.project1.ejb.allocation.EJSLocalStatelessAllocation_9d8d9db9.create(EJSLocalStatelessAllocation_9d8d9db9.java:55)
at com.cmp1.project1.ejb.allocation.AllocationClient.create(AllocationClient.java:116)
at com.cmp1.project1.service.processor.ProcessorImpl.processAllocationInstruction(ProcessorImpl.java:2917)
at com.cmp1.project1.service.processor.ProcessorImpl.processFIXMessage(ProcessorImpl.java:568)
at com.cmp1.project1.service.processor.ProcessorImpl.processSingleMessage(ProcessorImpl.java:459)
at com.cmp1.project1.service.processor.ProcessorImpl.processStagedMessage(ProcessorImpl.java:368)
at com.cmp1.project1.service.processor.ProcessorImpl.processMessage(ProcessorImpl.java:259)
at com.cmp1.project1.ejb.processor.ProcessorBean.processMessage(ProcessorBean.java:85)
at com.cmp1.project1.ejb.processor.EJSLocalStatelessProcessor_ac8a6492.processMessage(EJSLocalStatelessProcessor_ac8a6492.java:23)
at com.cmp1.project1.ejb.processor.ProcessorClient.processMessage(ProcessorClient.java:117)
at com.cmp1.project1.service.inbound.AsynchInboundHandlerImpl.process(AsynchInboundHandlerImpl.java:56)
at com.cmp1.project1.ejb.serviceactivator.ServiceActivatorBean.onMessage(ServiceActivatorBean.java:77)
at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.MDBWrapper$PriviledgedOnMessage.run(MDBWrapper.java:302)
at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:63)
at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.MDBWrapper.callOnMessage(MDBWrapper.java:271)
at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.MDBWrapper.onMessage(MDBWrapper.java:240)
at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.run(MQSession.java:1695)
at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSSessionHandle.run(JMSSessionHandle.java:1040)
at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSession.connectionConsumerOnMessage(ServerSession.java:1030)
at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSession.onMessage(ServerSession.java:710)
at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSession.dispatch(ServerSession.java:677)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor83.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSessionDispatcher.dispatch(ServerSessionDispatcher.java:44)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.MDBWrapper.onMessage(MDBWrapper.java:96)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.MDBWrapper.onMessage(MDBWrapper.java:132)
at com.ibm.ejs.jms.listener.ServerSession.run(ServerSession.java:535)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1497)
```

Code snippet:

```
    if(persistObj == null)
        return;

    Session session = sess; 
    try {
        if(session == null)
            session = HibernateUtil.getSession();

        if(LOG.isDebugEnabled() && 
           !(persistObj instanceof NonLoggable))
            log("update", persistObj);

        session.update(persistObj);

        if(flush)
            session.flush();

    } catch(StaleObjectStateException ex) {
        throw new HibernateStaleObjectException(ex);

    }
```

Comment: The issue is that once we get a staleobjectexception, it just does not stop. Every database update operation on that thread keeps giving staleobjectexception till we restart server.

Comment: Could it be a problem with duplicate ids? Does the row with id 37120123 exist?

Comment: Do you close the session when this exception happens?

Comment: @JBNizet: yep we are closing the session.

Comment: @ChetterHummin: no duplicate ids, have confirmed that several times. The fun part is even for some other id say 3473737 i get the same error message:  for com.cmp1.project1.hibernate.gen.Prjexe instance with identifier: 37120123

Comment: @siddheshjog: I have been experiencing this error as well. For me it is not just Staleobject but also the TransientObject NonUniqueObject as well. If you had resolved this, can you please share it here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you re-fetch your `persistObj` after doing an update? (Your code doesn't show that)

If not, that happens because you update the `persistObj`. After the update is done, you have an "old" version of `persistObj` in your class instance. If you want to update the `persistObj` again, you need to fetch the "current" version of `persistObj` again.

Comment: thanks. Will look into it. But apart from that, why is the exception stuck on the thread for ever and ever with the same error message same id , even if another instance with another id is being processed.